# HP ILO RIMP information?

Tags: hp, ilo

The HP ILO scripting guide gives an example of an unauthenticated xml query:
"https:///xmldata?item=all"

(See page 46, http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00294268/c00294268.pdf)

It also provides an example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<RIMP>
   <HSI> 
      <SBSN>0004PBM158</SBSN>
      <SPN>ProLiant DL380 G5</SPN>
      <UUID>1226570004PBM158</UUID> 
      <SP>1</SP> 
   </HSI>
  ....
```

But this response seems to be very different from RIBCL which I find to be very well documented. Different machines also seems to give slightly different responses as well (blade, oa, proliant..etc).

I am looking for any more information about this response and RIMP.

The HSI tag seems to be related to the machine itself and the MP tag to the ILO interface, is this correct?

Are there any other parameters possible besides "xmldata?item=all"?
Are there any major discover tools out there making use of this? I have found a few basic shell scripts.

Any suggestions would be appreciated 
Thank you, Skrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the HSI (Hardware Support Information?) Tag refers to the machine itself, and the MP (Management Processor) Tag the iLO.

xmldata?item=CpqKey will return licensing information such as advanced license key, install date etc. As far as I know these are the only two documented XML queries and I suspect by virtue of the name (cpq - compaq?), that they are a legacy item in the iLOs.

As far as network discovery, many scripts are written to see if they get a valid result from the URLs above - if not, then it is not an iLO as far as the script it concerned.

One such example for iLO discovery is located at http://blog.nachotech.com/?p=63 and uses a BASH script. I've written powershell scripts that do audits of iLO devices and they too scrape data from the xml URL.

Answer (score 0):

That response and tag information are used by other HP products like Systems Insight Manager, It's mostly association data, so that the SIM server can figure out which iLO corresponds to which system, and some generic details about the iLO.

Pretty much everything reported through xmldata?item=all is visible in the SIM UI.